# Output of dialog --checklist is not in quotes. How do I ensure output is quoted?

Tags: linux, dialog

A script I've inherited seems to have changed its behavior and I have been unable to figure out why.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Save response to this file
respFile=$1

dialog --backtitle "Test" \
--checklist "Observe the following expected conditions and \
confirm the actual results were detected by placing \
an X in any of the boxes.\n\n\
Leave the box blank if the actual result does not match the expected. \
\n\n \
Space bar toggles the X.\n \
Cursor selects a row.\n" \
25 60 6 \
1 "Condition A" off \
2 "Condition B" off \
3 "Condition C" off \
2> ${respFile}

# Ensure file is not zero length.
echo $0 >>${respFile}
echo $0 complete >> ${respFile}
```

Expected contents of respFile (after selecting options 1, 2, and 3):

```
"1" "2" "3" file.sh
file.sh complete
```

Actual contents of respFile:

```
1 2 3 file.sh
file.sh complete
```

I have tried inserting quotes around each option as below, but the quotes are ignored:

```
"1" "Condition A" off \
"2" "Condition B" off \
"3" "Condition C" off \
```

I have tried doubling the quotes as below

```
'"1"' "Condition A" off \
'"2"' "Condition B" off \
'"3"' "Condition C" off \
```

But then output turns into

```
"\"1\"" "\"2\"" "\"3\"" file.sh
file.sh complete
```

I have also tried reviewing this website (https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) for info on the --checklist box option where it mentions below.

"If the "--separate-output" option is not given, the strings will be quoted to make it simple for scripts to separate them. See the "--single-quoted" option, which modifies the quoting behavior."

As far as I can tell, my script should be producing a quoted output. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I suspect it only puts quotes around the value if it contains special characters like spaces.

Comment: I just confirmed that. I changed the value of condition B to be `2 2`, and it put quotes around it in the file.

Comment: Also tried and you are correct. But how come? According to the man page I linked, strings are quoted to make it simple for other scripts to separate them (which is why I want my output quoted). I have old response files which contain quoted integers, leading me to believe this script worked as expected at one time. Does 'dialog' need to be configured in a particular way?

Comment: Maybe there are different versions of the command.

Comment: what is output of `uname -srv`? Do you know if the old "dialogs" were run on a different OS? Good luck.

Comment: I believe it is related to an OS update with a different version of dialogs. I changed the list items to " 1 ", " 2 ", and " 3 " which included special characters as Barmar suggested. Only needed to make a minor change to the parsing script. Thanks everyone.